# CSV file update function that can be invoked with multiple object types

Tags: python, csv, oop, tkinter

I'm trying to create a function that updates a given csv file (as first argument) and updates it with a given object (as second argument). It is contained in my 'utils' package and will be invoked from UI.

So far, I've tried writing four separate functions (this is how many object types I currently have) and each function updates appropriate files differently. But this is not very reusable and easy to change in the future so I was wondering if there is a better way?
My Object hierarchy is as follows:

1. **User** has two subclasses: **Admin** and **Regular**
2. **Book** is a separate class describing a single book entity

Currently I have:

```
import shutil
import csv
import Users as usr
import Book as bk

def update_file(path, change):
    tempfile = NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False)

    with open(path, 'rb') as old_file, tempfile:
        reader = csv.reader(old_file, delimiter=',')
        writer = csv.writer(tempfile, delimiter=',')

        if isinstance(change, bk.Book):
            # Code for extracting appropriate data to update based on the object type
        elif isinstance(change, usr.User):
            # Code for extracting appropriate data to update based on the object type
        elif isinstance(change, usr.Admin):
            # Code for extracting appropriate data to update based on the object type
        elif isinstance(change, usr.Regular):
            # Code for extracting appropriate data to update based on the object type
        else:
            print("Object type not recognised")
            # Some error handling

        for row in reader:
            # Actual update code will be here

    shutil.move(tempfile.name, path)
```

This function will be invoked in different places in UI, something like this:

```
update_file(utils.USERS_FILE_PATH, user_type_object)
update_file(utils.USERS_FILE_PATH, regular_user_type_object)
update_file(utils.USERS_FILE_PATH, admin_user_type_object)
update_file(utils.BOOKS_FILE_PATH, book_type_object)
```

After I fill in the gaps with the extraction code this function will be very long and horrible to maintain, but having four separate functions (and possibly more if I implement new object types) seems like even worse idea.

I was also thinking about utilising **args** and **kwargs** in this function but haven't figured out how to do it without long list of **if-elif** statements.

Is there a better, more pythonic and more OOP way to do it?

Comment: You could give the objects a to_csv method. That way change can call it regardless of type.

Comment: Read up on [Tutorial - 9.5. Inheritance](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#inheritance) and implement `update_file` to get/write appropriate data.

Comment: Thanks @EricTruett, I will try that, as I already have __str__ implemented in all my classes so it seems like a logical place to have it

Answer (score 1):

[functools.singledispatch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.singledispatch) provides a way to dispatch functions based on the type of the *first* argument passed to a function.

```
from functools import singledispatch

@singledispatch
def extract(arg):
    # Perform default action
    raise TypeError(f"I don't know what to do with {arg}")

@extract.register(bk.Book)
def _(arg):
    # Perform book data extract
    return book_data

@extract.register(usr.User)
def _(arg):
    # Perform user data extract
    return user_data

# Define similar functions for other types
```

Using this technique, the code in the question would look like

```
def update_file(path, change):
    tempfile = NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False)

    with open(path, 'rb') as old_file, tempfile:
        reader = csv.reader(old_file, delimiter=',')
        writer = csv.writer(tempfile, delimiter=',')

        data = extract(change)

        for row in reader:
            # do stuff with data
```

If you are using Python 3.7 or later, you can use type annotations instead of setting the type in the decorator, if you want.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Have them all implement a method that returns the data for your csv. Then you just try to call that function. In Python you don't even have to set up inheritance to do it. You just try to call the function and catch exceptions.

```
# ...
writer = csv.writer(tempfile, delimiter=',')
try:
   # If it's just a row
   writer.write(change.get_cvs_data())
   # Alternatively, you pass the writer in the method call and let the object do the writing:
   change.write_csv(writer)
except AttributeError:
   # Here you can handle if object has not implemented the method you're using.
   pass
# ...
```